# ios::app causing problems

Tags: c++, file, binary

```
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
char ch;

class book
{
    char *title;
    char *author;
    double price;
    int quantity;
    public:
       book()
       {
            title=NULL;
            author=NULL;
            price=0.00;
            quantity=0;
       }
       void create(char *a, char *b, double x, int q)
       {
            title=new char;
            author=new char;
            strcpy(title, a);
            strcpy(author, b);
            price=x;
            quantity=q;
       }

       void display()
       {
           cout<<"\n"<<title<<"\t"<<author<<"\t"<<price<<"\t"<<quantity;
       }
 };

 book obj, obj2;

 fstream stock;

 void displaystock();

 void addbook()
 {
     cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";

     int n, i,q, j;
     stock.open("stock.txt", ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary);

     cout<<"\n\nHow many unique book titles would you like to add?";
     cin>>n;

     char *a, *b;
     double x=0;

     a=new char;
     b= new char;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
         cout<<stock.tellg();

         cout<<"\n\nEnter book title: ";
         gets(a);
         cout<<"\n\nEnter author: ";
         gets(b);
         cout<<"\n\nEnter price: ";
         cin>>x;
         cout<<"\n\nEnter quantity: ";
         cin>>q;

         obj.create(a,b,x, q);
         stock.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));

    }
    stock.close();
}

void displaystock()
{
    cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";

    stock.open("stock.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);
    cout<<stock.tellg();

    while(stock.read((char*)&obj2, sizeof(obj2)))       
    {   

        cout<<"\n"<<stock.tellg();

        //if(!stock.eof())
        {
            obj2.display();
        }
        //else
            //break;
    }

    stock.close();
}


int main()
{
    addbook();    
    displaystock();    
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code trying to write and read into a binary file using objects of a class. When the file doesn't exist (first time running), it works. But as soon as something is appended to an existing file, a segmentation fault appears while reading (in the displaystock function).

Comment: `ios::app` is almost certainly not the problem here.  You're code has serious issues (as others are answering about) that need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code. One thing I will point out here is this

```
 void create(char *a, char *b, double x, int q)
 {
     title=new char;
     author=new char;
     strcpy(title, a);
     strcpy(author, b);
     price=x;
     quantity=q;
}
```

You are declaring `title` and `author` to be of type `char*` and you are using them to copy the data from your input arguments a and b. You are only allocating memory for 1 char in the following

```
 title = new char;
```

when it is clear you are intending to treat it as an array when you strcpy. The result will be that you are highly likely to be writing into memory that you have not allocated because you haven't provided enough space to copy the data to. You would really really be better off using `std::string` for this. Also you have many many global variables littered within your code. Also

```
  stock.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));
```

is not good. Is it really meaningful to cast the address of an instance of your class `book` to a `char*` ? I would break your code down into simpler pieces, stop using so many global variables (consider passing things around using function arguments instead) and try to identify specific problems by stepping through your code with a debugger. Hopefully this will help you identify and fix some of the problems you have.

A final point - you are failing to delete any of the memory you allocate with `new`.